# Obj-C: dumping the hierarchy of the app views periodically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

We know that it is possible to dump the views hierarchy while in a breakpoint, using this debugger command:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

What is the best way to do the same periodically, so that each time the hierarchy is changed, the new hierarchy will be dumped to the log?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful implementation:

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
// This function will dump the app's view hierarchy periodically.
// No change - no printing
// 'gap_between_calls' comes in units of seconds.
// Tips: use times_to_run:1 to run once. use times_to_run:INT_MAX for non-stop
//
void dumpViewsHierarchyPeriodically(int times_to_run, float gap_between_calls)
{
    static NSMutableString *lastText = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        for (int i=0; i<times_to_run; i++) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
                int count = (int)windows.count;
                NSMutableString *txt = [NSMutableString new];
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                    UIWindow *wnd = windows[i];
                    #pragma clang diagnostic push
                    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
                    [txt appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nwindow[%i/%i]: %@",
                                       i+1, count, [wnd performSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]]];
                    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                }
                //log only if defferent than previous
                if (!lastText || ![txt isEqualToString:lastText]) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", txt);
                    lastText = txt;
                }
            });
            if (i+1 < times_to_run) {
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:gap_between_calls];
            }
        }
    });
}
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For a single run, the following can be used:

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
// This function will dump the app's view hierarchy
void dumpViewsHierarchy()
{
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    int count = (int)windows.count;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        UIWindow *wnd = windows[i];
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
        NSLog(@"\nwindow[%i/%i]: %@", i+1, count, [wnd performSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]);
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
    }
}
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I must admit that the periodic one it is sometimes crashing if running from Xcode, at the recursiveDescription call, showing this in the system log (iPod/9.0.2):  <Error>: assertion failed: 13A452: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15931 [45DE3123-E22D-320F-9F75-1CCD65A33451]: 0x0